# Python openpyxl How to bypass permissions to write to an open file

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to write a script that live edits an open excel file, but when I try to run the script that uses openpyxl and reads from a cell then writes data back to that cell with an edit, it gives this error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'GameExcel.xlsx'` is there a way around this using another module, or is there a secret I am missing

Edit here's the code, also this is just me learning before I integrate it into the full code.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as tkMsgBox
import time

os.chdir("D:\Scripts\Python\Testing Scripts\My Excel Game")
wb = load_workbook("GameExcel.xlsx")
names = wb.sheetnames
sheet = wb['GameEnviroment']

#userInput = (input("what would you like it to say?"))
#print(userInput)
C3Val = sheet['C4'].value

sheet.cell(row=3, column=4).value = (C3Val + ' 4')
wb.save('GameExcel.xlsx')
print(C3Val + ' 3')
#sheet['A1']=userInput
```

Comment: You cannot "live" edit an Excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option that I went with, and this only works with excel open, is xlwings

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the operating system limitation (ie Windows). It has nothing to do with openpyxl, Python or even Excel. [POSIX based OS do not have such a limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617452/opening-already-opened-file-does-not-raise-exception).

The answer  to this question ("How to bypass permissions to write to an open file") is simply "You can't".

Comment: is there a workaround? or do I need two identical excels that every time one updates the open one closes and updates while the updated one opens?

Comment: @Nickiel The only workaround would be to use another mechanism that allows concurrency, such as a database. Or a different operating system

Comment: database? is there a way to select and write text? I have been use a scripting language called autohotkey, so that is kinda what I am thinking in terms of how code structure is, haven't really gotten the hang of it.

Comment: @Nickiel Yes, that's kinda the purpose of databases

Comment: @Nickiel Without more context it's hard to give you concrete advice. Maybe something like [xlwings](https://www.xlwings.org/) does help you more? I think with xlwings it's possible to directly edit content in excel with python, instead of editing a file that excel than would need to read.

Comment: ok i'll look into those... can they write to an open excel file? or do they do something else?

Comment: I put the script in the question

Comment: Voted to close.  @Nickiel please don't be discouraged by SO and this isn't personal, the question doesn't fit SO's format as it is a "help me debug my code" problem.   That said, off the top of my head, perhaps a plugin running inside the spreadsheet software would work better, otherwise most applications lock the file to prevent something like this happening to avoid concurrent users corrupting the file.

Comment: ok, very well, I posted my code because @syntonym said he needed more context

Comment: would i have to write the plugin?

Comment: With more context I meant more what you actually want to archieve. DeepSpace answers your question that there is no way on windows to write to on already opened file. I would suggest looking into xlwings because there you can integrate python code with excel. If you have another concrete question I would suggest asking a new one here on SO.